# use a eventlistner click value for looped output from a function

Tags: javascript

Here's the code I have so far but it all makes the first baloon change and id like each div id clicked to supply the output to the div clicked. Not sure if I can combine this in an easy function or should I make 1 function for each div separately.

```
document.getElementById("baloon1").addEventListener("click", eggBasket);
document.getElementById("baloon2").addEventListener("click", eggBasket);
document.getElementById("baloon3").addEventListener("click", eggBasket);
function eggBasket(){
    var dispImages = new Array ();
    dispImages[1] = "images/1.png";
    dispImages[2] = "images/2.png";
    dispImages[3] = "images/3.png";
    dispImages[4] = "images/4.png";
    var rnd = Math.floor( Math.random() * dispImages.length );
        if( rnd == 0 ) {
        rnd =1;
        }
            if (document.getElementById("baloon1")){
                document.getElementById("baloon1").innerHTML = "<img src='" + dispImages[rnd] + "'/>";
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("baloon2")){
                document.getElementById("baloon2").innerHTML = "<img src='" + dispImages[rnd] + "'/>";
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("baloon3")){
                document.getElementById("baloon3").innerHTML = "<img src='" + dispImages[rnd] + "'/>";
            }
}
```

This is all in a scripts.js file being called to the php page.

Corrected the function name

Heres the html

```
echo'
<div id="baloon1">
    <img src="' . $randomImage . '">
</div>
<div id="baloon2">
    <img src="' . $randomImage2 . '">
</div>
<div id="baloon3">
    <img src="' . $randomImage2 . '"/>
</div>';
```

Comment: What does it have to do with PHP?

Comment: Strangely, PHP people think that things running in the browser have something to do with the server language. Hmmm.

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane Not PHP people, but the OP asking the question has this misunderstanding which we can clear IMHO

Comment: Please add the HTML sample this runs against and the function `eggBasket` which is not `Basket`

Comment: ok, 98% of the time, it's PHP.

Comment: I don't see a loop .. what exactly do you mean?

Comment: tried to correct the issues addressed above. Sorry I miss labeled a tag because im building a website. and the if else if else if isn't that considered a loop ? if not again my apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you are looking for, you want to pass the baloon's div ID to Basket to only modify that div.

```js
document.getElementById("baloon1").addEventListener("click", function(){Basket('baloon1');});
document.getElementById("baloon1").addEventListener("click", function(){Basket('baloon2');});
document.getElementById("baloon1").addEventListener("click", function(){Basket('baloon3');});

function Basket(divId){
    var dispImages = new Array ();
    dispImages[1] = "images/1.png";
    dispImages[2] = "images/2.png";
    dispImages[3] = "images/3.png";
    dispImages[4] = "images/4.png";
    var rnd = Math.floor( Math.random() * dispImages.length );
    if( rnd == 0 ) {rnd =1;}
    document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = "<img src='" + dispImages[rnd] + "'/>";
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for understanding and giving a working answer

Answer (score 1):

Here, we bind to each egg, same method.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.egg').forEach(egg => {
  egg.addEventListener("click", (event) =>  {
    console.log(`you clicked on ${event.target.id}`);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<div id="egg1" class="egg"> Egg1 </div>
<div id="egg2" class="egg"> Egg1 </div>
<div id="egg2" class="egg"> Egg3 </div>
```

Comment: for ECMAScript 6

Answer (score 1):

If you want each baloon to show a random image when clicked try something like this:

```js
[].slice
  //  find all divs containing an id containing baloon  
  .call(document.querySelectorAll('[id*=baloon]'))
  //  loop through all found divs 
  .map(function(baloon) {
    //  array of images to be randomized 
    var images = [
      'https://unsplash.it/100/?random=1',
      'https://unsplash.it/100/?random=2',
      'https://unsplash.it/100/?random=3',
      'https://unsplash.it/100/?random=4'
    ];

    //  pick a random image  
    var image = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

    //  add image to current baloon div 
    baloon.innerHTML = '<img src="' + image + '">';


    //  add click listener to baloon div 
    baloon.addEventListener('click', function() {

      //  pick a new random image
      var image = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

      //  add new image to current baloon div   
      baloon.innerHTML = '<img src="' + image + '">';

    })
  })
```

```css
[id*="baloon"] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="baloon1"></div>
<div id="baloon2"></div>
<div id="baloon3"></div>
```

In response to comment *(please note I'm not an expert on php)*

```
<?php
  //  print out images from dir to js array
  $images = array();
  foreach (glob("/IMAGEPATH/*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
    $images[] = $filename;
  }
  echo "<script>var images=" . json_encode($images) . "</script>";
 ?>
```

Comment: any way to do the images from an $array read from a folder by using json_encode or something ?

Comment: Yes - I've added a small php snippet to the answer :)

Comment: Thank you, I was missing echo "var" part of my trial. This worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all elements which id start with baloon like

```js
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="baloon"]')

for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) { 
    allElements[i].addEventListener('click', eggBasket)
}

function eggBasket(){
   console.log('clicked')
}
```

```html
<div id="baloon1" >baloon1</div>
<div id="baloon2" >baloon2</div>
<div id="baloon3" >baloon3</div>
```